# How to run Logstash-forwarder from client machine

Tags: logstash, logstash-forwarder

I am new to logstash. I installed elasticsearch, kibana, logstash and logstash-forwarder in Ubuntu from this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-logstash-and-kibana-to-centralize-and-visualize-logs-on-ubuntu-14-04) everything is fine while running on the local machine.
Now I want to include log file from another system so I installed logstash-forwarder on client machine but it fails to run. I cannot able to figure out mistake. In client machine I didn`t install logstash since logstash is running on server.If anything I misunderstood please let me know. What would be the configuration of server and client access.

Logstash forwarder in client:

```
{
  "network": {
    "servers": [ "server_ip_addr:5000" ],
    "timeout": 15,
    "ssl ca": "/etc/pki/tls/certs/logstash-forwarder.crt"
  },
  "files": [
    {
      "paths": [
        "/var/log/syslog",
        "/var/log/auth.log"
       ],
      "fields": { "type": "syslog" }
    }
   ]
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What's the error message? Second, where is the "ssl certificate" and "ssl key" path? Add them in part of network. Third, can all clients connect to logstash server with port 5000?

Comment: @ms74 have you got solution ? how ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install logstash-forwarder is enough.

Here are the ways to troubleshooting your problem.

1. Check if logstash is running on port 5000

Login logstash server, and run :

```
telnet localhost 5000
```

If you can't telnet, then make sure, logstash service is running properly.

2. Check if there are firewall issue between clients and logstash server.

Login client (where you installed forwarder on it)

```
telnet server_ip_addr 5000
```

If you can't, you need open the firewall port 5000 between client to logstash server.

3. In config file, the file part is fine, could you update the network part,

Let me know the result

```
"network": {
    "servers": [ "server_ip_addr:5000" ],
    "timeout": 15,
    "ssl certificate": "/etc/pki/tls/certs/logstash-forwarder.crt",
    "ssl key": "/etc/pki/tls/certs/logstash-forwarder.key",
    "ssl ca": "/etc/pki/tls/certs/logstash-forwarder.crt"
  },
```

Comment: I think firewall is blocking the port,In server logstash is running. logstash-forwarder.crt files in local only. I confused with network part can you instruct me how to open a firewall and ssl key and ssl certificate file configuration and i didnt get any error message while starting logstash-forwarder.

Comment: You can ignore the third part, if you don't have issue. (refer http://www.logstashbook.com/TheLogstashBook_sample.pdf, it works with your way).

Comment: I didn't know your environment, and can't give the suggestion on how to open firewall. Maybe you need check with your network provider. If your environment are in cloud, then you can set `security group` to enable the inbound port.

Comment: Problem is fixed.This is because of network issue.Thank You for guiding me.